# dijit.WidgetSet domNode

Tags: collections, dojo, widget

My custom Widget have a `collection` of child widgets that are constructed on AJAX response. So I need to maintain an `array` of child widgets and append the `domNode` of those widgets to its parent Widget's `domNode`.

I can use a `dijit.WidgetSet` make a collection of the `child widgets` but there is no `dijit.WidgetSet.domNodes()` method to get domNodes of all the widgets. also `dijit.WidgetSet` doesn't take care of placement of child nodes in its `parent DomNode`

Is there any other `class` for doing the same already ? e.g. would subclassing `dijit.WidgetSet` to take care of appending to parent domNode be a reinvetion of Wheel ?

Answer (score 0):

If you extend your parent with dijit._Container you can get hold of your widgetset by calling `parent.getChildren()`. The order in which widgets are returns is afaik the order that they were added to parent (`parent.addChild()`) and not by DOM sibling-hood. However, once you use the parser, this ofc would be the same. Well, any widget would have a getChildren implemented but the difference for _Container class is, that the `addChild: function(/*dijit._Widget*/ widget, /*int?*/ insertIndex)` and `removeChild: function(/*Widget|int*/ widget)` functions are pretty nifty. If you put an insertIndex while you add children, sibling-hood is manageable.

For concern of domNodes, with dijit we go 'beyond' DOM and work in the widget layer instead - which is only a JS wrap. The chainable function '.domNodes()' does not exist anywhere in dojo, you instead need to call similar to following:

```
parent.getChildren().forEach(function(childWidget) {
  var domNode = childWidget.domNode;
  ...
}); 

// this would get nowhere as the return child-set is merely a 'stupid' array
parent.getChildren().set("attribute", "value");
```

Here is a cute little wrapper for the above foreach, using dijit/map

```
// retreives an array of the actual domNodes of widgetset
dijit.registry.map(function(widget){return widget.domNode;}).forEach(
    // uses hitch to allow passing parameters without wrapping in new function
    dojo.hitch( 
        window,            // on random scope
        dojo.addClass,     // calling function
        "imTheChildDomNode"// arguments[0]
    )
);
```